# how to take database as parameter to connect to mysql database server

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database

```
import java.sql.*;
class ConnectSql
{
    static Connection cont(String db)throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db+","root","xyz" );  
        return(con);
    }
}
```

I am facing a problem in compiling this function and this 7th line is i suppose a problem is there an syntax error.If so please tell me.Here i want to take the name of database as parameter received from calling function.When i gave the exact name of database instead of parameter it worked,but not after i passed parameter in connection line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db,"root","xyz" );
```

problem is

```
"+db+"
```

you have extra `"` mark

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection con=null;

String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String USER = "abc";//db user name
String PASS = "abc";//db password     


public synchronized Connection getConnection(String dbname)
{
 try
    {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//loading mysql driver 
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL+dbname,USER,PASS);//connecting to mysql
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to take the input of dbname from user